# How do I make JAR and WAR on IntelliJ IDEA?

Tags: maven, amazon-web-services, intellij-idea, aws-lambda

I want to develop a new java `webservice` to be deployed on `AWS Lambda`, but I also want to be able to easily test it.

My idea is to code my `webservice` using `Jersey` and be able to compile it into a `war` file, so I can test it localy and also be able to compile it into a `jar` for the [`Serverless Java container`](https://github.com/awslabs/aws-serverless-java-container) from AWS.

My first thought was to create 2 modules on `IntelliJ IDEA 2017.3 Ultimate`, one for the `war`and one for the `jar`, all using Maven, with the 2 modules sharing the same code base for the `Jersey REST Resources` (the `webservice` classes). But unfortunately I am too new to `IntelliJ IDEA` and I can't put this to work.

Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: So - do you need help with Maven or with IDEA?

Comment: Maven on IDEA, so mostly Maven I guess

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution you provided is workable but IMO overcomplicated a bit. I did something similar for my project: first I made a [module](https://github.com/project-avral/oo-atom/tree/master/atom-basis) with all the sources and tests, then I sliced it to [different](https://github.com/project-avral/oo-atom/blob/master/atomizer/pom.xml) [artifacts](https://github.com/project-avral/oo-atom/blob/master/atom-tests/pom.xml). It's not the cleanest solution though - you have a risk of placing dependent classes to different artifacts and cause classloading issues in runtime.

In your case it is simpler - you only need to repackage same content to another artifact, if I get it right. In simplest case, one module would be enough. You can just add a plugin for assembling WAR archive, like that:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>jarwar</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.1.1</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>war</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <classifier>web</classifier>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

The example above will compile the sources, assemble jar and war archives from them at packaging phase, and attach them for further installation and deployment. Main idea here is to execute both `maven-jar-plugin:jar` and `maven-war-plugin:war` goals at packaging phase, when all the sources are compiled. The first goal is bound at `jar` default packaging, and the second one is bound explicitly.

One more important detail is classifier: it should be specified on one of the artifact to mark it as supplementary. Otherwise the artifacts won't be installed to repositories correctly.

Comment: Interesting... I will try!

Comment: Ok... I will do my readings on artifacts and goals and then I will try it thanks a lot!

Comment: Could you elaborate more on "you have a risk of placing dependent classes to different artifacts and cause classloading issues in runtime"?

Comment: Well, this risk is actual only in the case when you split your compiled classes to different artifacts (like I do in my project). In such cases you may break the class and its imported classes to different archives, and if for some reason, later in runtime classpath, there will be only archive with class but without its imports, you'll get classloading issues. Anyway - it's nothing to worry about in your case - as I get it from your question, you are only repackaging the same content, not slicing it.

Comment: I think so... Thanks!

Comment: Was the answer helpful? If so - could you please approve it?

Comment: Yes, at the end I made it differently, with a special module for the war so I can place some webserver configurations and code that won't go with the main core webservice code to the lambda package.... And the same for a lambda module... I know it's more complicated, but I want the flexibility.